# How can I read CD-Text information from CDs

Tags: application, audio-cd

What applications are available for GNU/Linux that allow read-out of CD-Text data from CDs?

Command-line programs would be preferred.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Libcdio](http://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/) contains a collection of command-line which are CD-Text aware. Specifically, you can get CD information using the **`cd-info`** program.

For more information on using particular `libcdio` library functions, have a look at the [online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/libcdio.html).

Comment: To get `cd-info` on **Debian**, install the `libcdio-utils` package.

Comment: try to use `cdda-player -l` (in the same package)